# MacTex 2016 issue with emerald font installation

Tags: mactex, installing-fonts

Using MacTex 2016 under OS X El Capitan (all package updated)

I was following rules https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html.

1/ Download emerald.zip from CTAN.

2/ unzip files in `/opt/share/texmf-local/` (merging `doc` and `tex/latex` directories with existing ones).

3/ Execute :

```
sudo -H mktexlsr. 
sudo -H updmap-sys --force --enable Map=emerald.map
sudo -H mktexlsr.
```

4/ compile `testfont.tex` with `pdftex testfont.tex` -> OK.

First error :

```
When compiling with "texstudio" \usepackage{emerald} gives the error "File 'emerald.sty' not found. \ECFDecadence".
```

I have copied `emerald` folder (containing `.sty` file and `.fd` files) in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`.

Second error :
When compiling `..\usepackage{emerald} \ECFDecadence ...` I obtain :

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm fdcmd8te

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input fdcmd8te

This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2016/MacPorts 2016_1) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf fdcmd8te

! I can't find file `fdcmd8te'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input fdcmd8te Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input fdcmd8te Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: fdcmd8te.log: No such file or directory

mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input fdcmd8te' failed to make fdcmd8te.tfm. kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

I don't understand what's happening ....

Comment: You say you have MacTeX, but the log says MacPorts. Remove the MacPorts installation and install MacTeX.

Comment: Don't copy the folder to `~/Library`. Install it under `/opt` with the rest.

Comment: @egreg : I am using the software "Auto Multiple Choice" (http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/) which require some latex package install with MacPorts only, so I need MacPorts. MacTex 2016 is already installed.

Comment: @cfr : emerad folder is already in /opt/local/share/texmf-local/tex/latex

Comment: Then you need to do the install *twice*, or convince TeXStudio to use the MacPorts distribution.

Comment: @egreg Can you feed MacPorts a dummy package? @ OP If it is you your `TEXMFLOCAL`, then you don't need it in `TEXMFHOME` also. But having multiple installations of TeX Live is not recommended, except for the installation of different years' editions from upstream (e.g. MacTeX 2015 and 2016 is OK). You can do it if you know what you're doing, but you have to make sure the installations are kept properly distinct.